# Visual Studio Code - 'command python.runtests not found' what is this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I'm using Visual Studio Code to develop a python project and when I select the option to run all unit tests, I get the following error:
'command 'python.runtests' not found

In my project I'm the unittest package and I have a settings.json file that has the following configuration (see below):

```
{

    "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [ "-v","-s", ".//Test", "-p", "*_test.py" ],
    "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false
}
```

All my unit tests classes are under a folder called Test folder.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem? Reinstalling "Python" extension didn't help :(

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to reinstall the Python extension. Instead, enable the `Jedi` Python Language Server:

```
{
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi",

    "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": ["-v", "-s", ".//Test", "-p", "*_test.py"],
    "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false
}
```

Note that the setting `python.jediEnabled` has been removed in favor of the `python.languageServer` setting according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62470810/6116066) referring to [this VSCode changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#202060-16-june-2020).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and it was common to all my Python workspaces

The solution for me was nice and simple though - simply uninstall the VSCode Python extension and then reinstall it.

Robert