# vscode "python.jediEnabled": false, showing as Unknown Configuration Setting

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

this is the settings.json file code

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft"
}
```

in this `"python.jediEnabled": false`, showing error that Unknown Configuration Setting pleaase give the solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python)'s release on June 16th 2020 they removed the `python.jediEnabled` setting in favor for the `python.languageServer` setting.
From the [changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#202060-16-june-2020):

> Removed `python.jediEnabled` setting in favor of `python.languageServer`. Instead of `"python.jediEnabled": true` please use `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"`.
>      ([#7010](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7010))