# "Unknown Configuration Setting" in VSCode. Where to find current VSCode Python configurations for settings.json?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Similar issues have been posted like [vscode "python.jediEnabled": false, showing as Unknown Configuration Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470439/vscode-python-jedienabled-false-showing-as-unknown-configuration-setting)

I was really struggling now setting up my flake8 settings in VSCode to extend the E501-line-too-long-Error with

```py
"python.linting.flake8Args": ["--max-line-length=120"]
```

After searching the [Python Github Repo of VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python), I finally found this [post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Migration-to-Python-Tools-Extensions) to realize the settings have changed to

```py
"flake8.args": ["--max-line-length=120"]
```

Now, my question is where do I find the current python configurations like `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"`?
I could neither find it in the Github Repo nor on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), even though on [flake8's marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8) settings are listed below.

Comment: search the settings GUI for `flake8` or `python`

Comment: Wow so simple! Thats the answer I needed a while ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the extensions have a `Configuration` section which list the name of the keys used by the `settings.json` file to store extension preferences.
Another, more roundabout way, is to open the settings UI, find the setting you want to change, and click on the `Open in settings.json` button, this will give you the name of the key you needed.

Comment: Cannot really find a Configuration section anywhere in my settings UI but this answers my question. I would add that after saving the settings UI, I can see the changes in my settings.json too. Thanks :)

Comment: The Configuration section is found when you are browsing an extension. Sorry if I sounded confusing about that in my answer.